# Using the grep operation for my local mail inbox

Tags: grep, cron, email

I am trying to record each mail sent to my local inbox from the cron job in to another *txt* file. When I use the line

```
mail | grep cron > cron_mail.txt
```

the operation does not stop and creates an empty *cron_mail.txt*.

How would I fix this, or is there an easier way to complete this operation in bash?

Comment: Why do you need it, maybe you only want to turn log file for cron?

Comment: That sounds like it would work better, could you direct me to any good resources for that operation?

Comment: what distro you have? default logs is sended to syslog, you can redirect it to cron.log in rsyslog.d (uncoment line with cron in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mail outputs to the standard error stream, so that it doesn't get piped to grep, as only standard output is piped.

Try `mail 2>&1 | grep cron > cron_mail.txt`

2 is the file descriptor of the standard error stream, and  with the command above, it will get redirected to standard output, which in turn gets piped.

Answer (score 0):

If your local mail spool is a Berkeley mailbox file, try

```
grep '^From cron  ' "$MAIL"
```

This relies on the fact that Berkeley mbox files use a line starting with `From`, the sender's envelope address, and two spaces (usually followed by the message's arrival time) as the separator line fefore each new message. (A consequence of this is that the message body cannot contain the five characters `From` at beginning of line anywhere in it.) If your `cron` daemon's messages contain e.g. a FQDN domain name, you'll obviously need to adapt the regex.

Berkeley mbox used to be ubiquitous, but these days, many systems use other mailbox formats, many of which are folder-based, rather than a single flat file. For maildir, a common format especially for IMAP mailboxes, try

```
find new cur tmp -type f -exec grep -m 1 '^From:' /dev/null | grep cron
```

which examines the `From:` header in each message (this is distinct from the similarly labelled Berkeley separator line, which isn't a mail header at all). You'd run this in the folder you want to examine, or include the full path to the `new`, `cur`, and `tmp` subdirectories in the directory arguments.